# Filtering before join to avoid "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2008 and trying to write a query in a SSIS Package data flow task to read data from one data base based on the result set from another DB.

I have multiple tables A, B, C, D, E etc and I am trying to write a select that joins these tables and get the data after a filter. I am getting a "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error on the following query

```
SELECT
A.1 as A1,

A.2 as A2,

A.3 as A3,

B.1 as B1,

(Select C.1 from C 

        left join cc on c.2 = cc.2

        where C.x = A.x) as C1,

(Select D.1 from D where D.x = A.x) as D1,

E.4 as E4

FROM A

 left join B on B.Y = A.Y

 inner join C on C.Y = A.Y

 inner join D on D.Y = C.X

 left join E on E.Y = D.Z AND E.Z = 'ZZZZ'

WHERE A.P = ?
```

The general structure of the query is as above and the query runs fine if I remove the where clause completely or give a simple `"WHERE A.P = 'PPPP'"`. It appears simple enough and I am not using any data from the sub queries in the where clause. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the two databases on the same SQL Server? Where exactyl do you get the error? when you preview it? When you run it? When you define parameters? Have you defined parameters successfully for this query?

Comment: In the process of sanitising the query for posting you have most likely accidentally removed the coding issue, because there is nothing wrong with that query, assuming all the tables and columns exist.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the reference cannot be bound to an object.  However, it doesn't refer to the column part of the expression, just the part before that.

So, if `P` is not column in `A`, then `A.P` will generate an error like "Column not found".  If `A` is not defined in the `from` clause, then `A.P` will give you the `multi-part identifier not found error".

A common reason is misusing an alias.  If you have code like this:

```
from TableA a
where TableA.col . . .
```

Then you will get the error.  Although `TableA` is in the `from` clause, it is known in the query by its alias `A`, not by the table name.  This can also happen because you have mistyped a table name, schema name, database name, or server name in an expression.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. After reading little bit more about this issue, instead of using sql by command in SSIS and pass the parameter, i decided to build the entire sql in a script task and use sql by command or variable option. I was able to pass in the parameter to the script and append it to my query as required. Appreciate all your suggestions.

Comment: @IKONOSI . . . I have a bias for SQL scripts over SSIS.